# How do I populate a field depending on which button a user clicks?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

This would act similar to an "add to cart" function using asp.net core. So for example if a someone clicks on a button next to an image of a burger, it should be redirected to an `Order` create page, with the ProductName field populated with the text "Burger".
I've tried using `@Html.ActionLink` but this only directs you to a new page and does not populate the field. What are alternatives methods to populate fields when you press a button.

[This is the button that needs to populate the ProductName field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxuaI.jpg)

[This is what the end result should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1zqH.jpg)

Any tips or suggestions will be much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: You can use `asp-route-param="@Model.Name"`, then use the parameter ·`string param` in your create method in the background to accept it, and finally pass it to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `asp-route` taghelper to pass data to the backend.

```
 <a asp-action="Create" asp-route-name="@Model.Name">ADD TO CART</a> |
```

Then in your `Create` action.Use ViewData to pass the name to the view.

```
 public IActionResult Create(string name)
    {
        ViewData["Name"] = name;
        return View();
    }
```

Then in your view,change your code to:

```
 <input value="@ViewBag.Name" name="ProductName" class="form-control" />
```

to get the name you sended.